# Generating dependent data

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

For some training I'd like to create some fake data. I need help figuring out how to create dependent random values - There are a number of them, but for brevity the below example shows me generating a Subscribe_Year value and Last_Call value. I need Subscribe_Year to always be <= the value generated in Last_Call. How would I do this?

```
Cust_Details = pd.DataFrame({"Cust_ID" : random.sample(range(10000, 30000), k=1932),
             "Subscribe_Year" : np.random.choice(range(0,4), 1932, p=[.2,.1,.3,.4],  replace=True), 
             "Last_Call" : np.random.negative_binomial(5,0.1, 1932))
```

Comment: Do you want the dependent and independent variables to have some specific relationship.. <= is a very broad one..

Comment: For the example i'm okay with a random relationship with values between 0 and 5 as long as it meets <=. If what i'm asking doesn't make sense, I'm happy for your suggestion?